# Javascript object with square brackets in the name

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a javascript object to submit a form. One property must be an array of ids, see below:

```
var customPostData = {
    lecturer:$("#modulesessform").serializeArray()[0].value,
    topic:$("#topic").val(),
    sessionType:$("#sessionType").val(),
    sessionDate:$("#sessionDate").val(),
    startTime:$("#startTime").val(),
    endTime:$("#endTime").val(),
    sessionStatus:$("#sessstatus").val(),
    attendedstudents:studentsattended.toSource()                                                                           
};
```

Here is what that looks like in the post data.

```
attendedstudents    ["7348", "6472", "7392", "7235", "7399", "6943"]
endTime 8:30 PM
lecturer    5582
sessionDate Tuesday, October 02, 2012
sessionStatus   Completed
sessionType 1
startTime   5:30 PM
topic   bla
```

The problem is the last field. I want to be able to say `attendedstudents[]:studentsattended.toSource`.
You see I am using spring MVC and in order to tell it that this parameter is a collection of some kind I need the `[ ]` as part of the name-value pair. Here is a small snippet:

```
public @ResponseBody String ajaxcreate( @PathVariable("si") Long si,
                                        @RequestParam("sessionDate") @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy") java.util.Calendar sessionDate,
                                        @RequestParam("startTime") @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm a") java.util.Calendar startTime,
                                        @RequestParam("endTime") @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm a") java.util.Calendar endTime,
                                        @RequestParam("attendedstudents[]") ArrayList<Long> attendedstudents,
                                        Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {//bla bla bla}
```

See the very last `@RequestParam`. I tried it without the square brackets in spring, but that throws errors. I also tried using an array of strings and parse the string as a long, see below.

```
 @RequestParam("attendedstudents") String[] attendedstudents
```

This produced this exception. Apparently, it's trying to parse the square bracket as part of the string.

> For input string: "["7348""
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
>   java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:410)
>   java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:525)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose it in **Quotes**

```
'attendedstudents[]' :
```

Comment: Both answers are correct and work fine. Thanks Asad and sushanth, you guys rock !

Comment: @Binaryrespawn .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Square brackets are valid in key names, you just need to use them as part of a string literal.

```
customPostData["attendedstudents[]"]=studentsattended.toSource();
```